# How to check internet connection in background state in ionic

Tags: ionic3, background-service, internet-connection

Hello all i want to check internet connection while application is in the background state in ionic 3 how can i do this for android as well as in ios.
Please help me on this.
I tried ionic-native/network but it is not working in background.

Comment: Did you try to use background plugin and inside it to implement the network plugin?

Comment: @MostafaHarb i tried it but it is not working.

Comment: There is a plugin in ionic named background-network, test it it should do what you need.

Comment: @MostafaHarb can you provide me a git link of it please?

Answer (score 0):

***Md/Ios Background Ionic plugin:***
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode

This the normal ionic background plugin and bellow link is a demo on how to use it:
https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-keep-it-running-in-background-using-cordova-and-ionic-native-plugins/amp/

If that is not what you want to achieve, and you need the app to be active even after user force close it you can use:

***Force IOS background plugin:***
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-fetch

This  background-fetch plugin works for ios only so use it to achieve your aim for ios.

***Force Android background plugin:***
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-scheduler

```
npm i cordova-plugin-scheduler
```

This is scheduler plugin which works only for android and you could also achieve your aim in android

And this is reference of android about the schedular:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler

Comment: I implemented it background-mode is working perfectly but network changes is not working like i am switching off my internet or connect the internet network.onConnect event is not working

Comment: @sakhiya dhruv, same issue, how do you resolve this?

Comment: for such cases, i believe you can't reach that specification about internet through those plugins.. So best case is to develop your own native android and ios foreground service and specify those specific cases like getting event of network change or device started or such things and bining your logic into those type of events..